# Cannot install wine32 in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: wine, 16.10

I have upgraded from Ubuntu `16.04`. `Wine` was installed in my system but after upgrade it was returning the following error.

```
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
```

So I purge wine and reinstall using following steps

```
1. sudo apt install wine-stable
2. WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32
3. wine #return error
4. wineboot
```

But still, when I try to run anything using `wine` it's shows `wine32` is missing. So I tried to install `win32`.

```
sudo apt install wine32
```

## error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 1.8.5-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
```

## System info

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety
```

Comment: Have you tried installing libwine:i386? If so what error does it give?

Comment: Yes, I tried to go multiple level. There are lots of dependencies error.

Answer (score 17):

Would you give this a try on a fresh `WINEPREFIX`?

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install wine32
```

If still broken, try:

```
$ sudo apt -f install
```

Or more powerfully:

```
$ sudo aptitude -f install wine32
```

Just remember to **READ carefully** what aptitude is asking, for it could remove some packages along the way. It can give you **several suggestions.** You may keep trying and check which one can work for you, or what the source of the problem is.

Otherwise you may try **`PlayOnLinux`** as it separates each virtual machine, so you may have a better chance of a cleaner install.

As a last recourse, a badly messed up system may be a good sign for a fresh Ubuntu install. ;-)

Comment: Same issue. After that, I still get "wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 1.8.5-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed"

Comment: After that could you follow up the command with:
`$ sudo apt -f install` ...?

Comment: A stronger way to follow it up will be `$ sudo aptitude -f install wine32`. Just remember to READ what `aptitude` is asking for it could remove some packages along the way...

Comment: aptitude is suggesting to leave a series of dependencies (*heimdal*) as not installed, which is of course not solving anything. Alternatively, it is suggesting uninstalling 129 packages, including libreoffice, gnome-shell...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions; I've been able to solve my issue (see below).

Comment: `aptitude` can give you several suggestions. You may keep trying and check which one can work for you. I'm running 16.10 also and have no problem with wine32. Oh BTW, have you tried `PlayOnLinux` instead? It separates each virtual machine, so you may have a better chance of a cleaner install... Otherwise, it may be time for a fresh Ubuntu install? ;-)

Comment: I also had same issue and also follow the aptitude process and carefully read the solutions which was suggested by aptitude and one of solution is corrected my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are trying to run on 64bit machine.

Run below script

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

Once you have installed 32bit wine in your ubuntu then try running `*.exe` by

```
wine <executable-name>.exe
```

Hope the error will not appear and wait for few seconds to open exe file. it depends upon on your machine configurations

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Majal, tried running

```
sudo aptitude -f install wine32
```

This mentioned that a bunch of *heimdal*:i386 files could not be installed, as the version of the x86_64 package was different.

```
libroken18-heimdal : Breaks: libroken18-heimdal:i386 (!= 1.7~git20160703+dfsg-1) but 1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

It turns out that I had a higher version of the x86_64 packages than what was available in the repositories (probably some PPA with only x86_64 packages?).

So, using synaptic I have downgraded all the *heimdal* packages, and then I've been able to install wine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Linux Mint 20. Installing both x64 and x86. Tho when I tried to apt install wine32 I would get the response that it was already installed.  Here is what I eventually did and it worked for me.

```
# if you are on x64 system first enable 32 bit arch with
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

# remove the original WINEPREFIX and create dir for wine32 WINEPREFIX
$ rm -r ~/.wine
$ mkdir ~/.wine32

# now install or reinstall wine32 and create WINEPREFIX
# an often missed step is including the :i386
$ sudo apt reinstall wine32:i386
$ WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot

# and optionally create wine64 WINEPREFIX and its dir by entering
$ WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine" WINEARCH=win64 wine64 wineboot

# check your work
$ wine --version
```

You should now have wine32 installed and if you needed it also wine64.