# How can I install Adobe reader on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: wine, adobe, winetricks, adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to install Acrobat reader on Ubuntu latest version. I followed the step by step instructions in [this web site](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-latest-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux-with-wine), but when I try to execute the wine commands

```
wine AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe
```

I got the following error:

> ```
> it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
> as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
> it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
> as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
> wine: Mauvais format EXE pour Z:\home\morad\Téléchargements\AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe.
> ```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error suggests:
`sudo apt-get install wine32`

Comment: when I try the execute this command I get the following messages :                                              `Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 wine32:i386 : Dépend: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».`

Comment: @moradov It helps if you run your error messages through a translator first, as the majority of this site is English-speaking.  Rough translation of that message: `The following packages contain unmet dependencies: wine32: i386: Depends: libwine: i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but will not be installed E: Unable to fix problems, defective packages are in "keep as is" mode .`

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f` to see if it can fix the dependency problem?

Comment: aptitude may guide you through resolving the dependency issue: `sudo aptitude -f install wine32`,
as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/859563/cannot-install-wine32-in-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: i tried to use:` sudo aptitude -f install wine32` after installing aptitude, but it still not done, i get the same issue when I tried to use wine `wine AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe 
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine: Mauvais format EXE pour Z:\home\morad\Téléchargements\AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe.`