# how can I disable the dependency libwine:i386 library to install wine32:i386 on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit?

Tags: 18.04, wine

I'm going to install acrobat reader on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit, I had already asked the same question [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060107/how-can-install-wine32-on-ubuntu-18-04-64bit?noredirect=1#comment1734844_1060107).

I thought this problem is related to some libraries, I installed libxml2-dev, without having to eliminate the dependancy  libwine:i386, i got the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

> Reading package lists ... Done
>    Building the dependency tree 
>    Reading status information ... Done 
>    Some packages can not be installed. This
>   can mean that you asked for the impossible, or, if you use the
>   unstable distribution, that some packages have not yet were created or
>   did not come out of Incoming. The following information should help
>   you resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages contain unmet dependencies:   wine32: i386:
>   Depends: libwine: i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but will not be installed E:
>   Unable to fix problems, defective packages are in "keep as is" mode.

**update**
i had tried to install wineHQ, but when i use the following commands [from here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), i get this result, what i can do to fix it:

```
 morad@morad-Vostro-1540:~/Téléchargements$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
Fichier «Release.key» déjà présent ; pas de récupération.

    morad@morad-Vostro-1540:~/Téléchargements$ sudo apt-key add Release.key
    OK
    morad@morad-Vostro-1540:~/Téléchargements$ sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
    Atteint:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
    Atteint:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                  
    Atteint:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
    Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                   
    Ign:5 http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                                                                                         
    Atteint:6 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                           
    Réception de:7 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release [8 180 B]                                                                        
    Réception de:8 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg [181 B]                                                                      
    Atteint:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                             
    Atteint:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                         
    Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
    Atteint:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
    Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release        
      404  Not Found [IP : 91.189.95.83 80]
    Ign:8 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
    Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release        
      404  Not Found [IP : 91.189.95.83 80]
    Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait                             
    W: La cible Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr_FR) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    E: Le dépôt http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release n'a pas de fichier Release.
    N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut
    N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
    W: Erreur de GPG : http://archive.canonical.com precise Release : Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
    E: Le dépôt http://archive.canonical.com precise Release n'est pas signé.
    N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut
    N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
    E: Le dépôt http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release n'a pas de fichier Release.
    N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut
    N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
    W: La cible Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr_FR) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:5 et /etc/apt/sources.list:9
    morad@morad-Vostro-1540:~/Téléchargements$
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd highly recommend following the instructions on the WineHQ website [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu). This will add repositories that will allow you to maintain the most up to date version of wine, as Ubuntu's own repositories aren't always the newest versions of software (for stability reasons mostly).

Once you've picked either the winehq-stable or winehq-staging package to install, you'll need to create a wineprefix. This is simply a container with a Windows directory structure where you will install your software. Do not run any wine commands to run software just yet, as it will create a default 64 bit wineprefix, which will be a hidden folder in your $HOME directory (~) called .wine. Instead, do the following:

```
WINEPREFIX=$HOME/prefix32 WINEARCH=win32
```

You can change where you want the wineprefix to be, if you don't want it in ~, as well as the name of the folder. Keep in mind that if you have multiple prefixes, you will need to specify which prefix to use. If you create one prefix for 32 bit, and another for 64 bit, you will need to run the above command with the prefix pointing to the location of the one you wish to use.

For example, if you have downloaded the setup file for Adobe, you will then run:

```
WINEPREFIX=$HOME/prefix32 wine setup.exe
```

Replace setup.exe with whatever the name of your installer may be.

With all that being said, you could also look into native applications as an alternative to Acrobat Reader. The qpdfview package is lightweight, and should have all the features most people will need from a .pdf viewer.

Comment: use `wine wineboot` instead of some random `wine setup.exe` at first startup of your wineprefix with the selected arch.

Answer (score 0):

i used winehq too, when i install wine32 or wine64, it's not comfortable to me, so i install this [winehq](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install winehq-stable
```

I am also a user 64bit, before i remove default folder and so i can change 32 to 64 as

```
WINEPREFIX=$HOME/wine64 WINEARCH=win64 winecfg
```

and i can any windows applications provided that all libraries are needed can installed.

**UPDATE ANSWERED**

you add repo with

```
morad@morad-Vostro-1540:~/Téléchargements$ sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

but your using bionic, instead with

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @moradov please check update answered